# Writing specific value from database to HTML via AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

First time question, hoping for some advice:

Code on webpage:

```
<form id="inbound" action="javascript:validateinbound();">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" id="inbound">
    <script>
        function validateinbound() {
            $('#inbound:input').each(function () {
                var iv = $(this).val();
                $('#response').hide();
                $('#mydiv').fadeIn(1200);
                $('#mydiv').delay(1200).fadeOut(600);
                $(function () {
                    $.ajax( {
                        url: 'validateinbound.php',
                        data: "variable="+iv,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var response = JSON.stringify(data);
                                $('#response').delay(3600).fadeIn(600);
                                $('#response').append("<p>Answer: </p>"+response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        };
    </script>
</form>
```

This returns a string that I would like to work with that looks like this:

Answer:

```
 [{"id":"1","answer":"Pull  logging","question_id":"5","feature_id":"1","answer_id":"9"}]
```

Ideally what I would like to do is only select the 'value' to the maxmail_answer 'key' (hopefully those are the right terms?) to the webpage instead. Right now there is only one value but there will be more in the future so something that could parse this string for a specific key and only output those values.

Visually I would see:

Answer: Pull logging ( and then another Answer: for each value I pull out )

First time ever using this site and these languages so total noob and would appreciate some guidance.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Thank you to everyone who commented on this to help me get started in the right direction. I was able to get what I needed working!! Here is the solution:

```
<form id="inbound" action="javascript:validateinbound();">
<input type="submit" value="Go!" id="inbound">
<script>
function validateinbound() {
$('#controlpanel:input').each(function () {
var iv = $(this).val();
$('#response').html("");
$('#response').hide();
$('#mydiv').fadeIn(1200);
$('#mydiv').delay(1200).fadeOut(600);
$(function () {
$.ajax( {
url: 'validateinbound.php',
data: "variable="+iv,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
var newdata = JSON.stringify(data);
var response = JSON.parse(newdata);
$('#response').delay(3600).fadeIn(600);
$.each(response, function(array, object) {
$('#response').append("<p>Answer: </p>"+object.answer);
});
}
});
});
});
};
</script>
</form>
```

I needed to parse the data correctly. So I used JSON.stringify to get the data into a string that JSON.parse could use to manipulate the data. But function(index,object) wouldn't work because my output was not an index, but an array. So when changing to function(array,object) this allowed me to get my data just the way that I needed.

Again thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

You do not to stringify the JSON response, you can get the value of the key you want using the object notation `.` as follows:

```
function validateinbound() {
            $('#inbound:input').each(function () {
                var iv = $(this).val();
                $('#response').hide();
                $('#mydiv').fadeIn(1200);
                $('#mydiv').delay(1200).fadeOut(600);
                $(function () {
                    $.ajax( {
                        url: 'validateinbound.php',
                        data: "variable="+iv,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
         //var response = JSON.stringify(data); // no need for this line
         $('#response').delay(3600).fadeIn(600);
         // catch the answer here
         // your result returns within an array so you need to catch the first index
         $('#response').append("<p>Answer: </p>"+response[0].answer); 
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        };
```

Besides, ids are unique, you can only access a single element via id selector `#`, you do not need a `.each`

Comment: So this works perfectly for pulling back one piece of data. I have added a second piece of data to the JSON and need to know how to get both. I tried using sujan's $.each statement but I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Yes you need a `$.each` method, but you need to make sure the returned JSON is well formatted and resembles a javascript array. Is it always an array at response or could it be an object sometimes, based on a certain action or input?

Comment: Hey KAD, thanks again for the help. So it should always be formatted as an array. This is basically the output of a PHP query to a MySQL database with an echo json_encode($data) call that I wanted to manipulate. The string will always follow the format in my post, just with different values. The 'answer' will always be constant and will always be in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

What you are receiving from your server is an array of objects in the JSON format.  The sample that you have put has the length of "1" and therefore, if want to reach the "id" of the first array, it would be like this:

```
// var response = JSON.stringify(data); (// don't stringify it!
$('#response').delay(3600).fadeIn(600);
$('#response').append("<p>Answer: </p>"+data[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Json.stringify()` returns your javascript object as json data, but i think in your case your response is a json data which you need to manipulate. `Json.parse()` does this for you and you can access your answer as a property of the javascript object.

```
success: function(data) {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#response').delay(3600).fadeIn(600);
    $('#response').append("<p>Answer: </p>"+response[0].answer);
}
```

if your json data has multiple result and you need to work through all of them use a loop.

```
$.each(response,function(index, object){

    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#response').delay(3600).fadeIn(600);
    $('#response').append("<p>Answer: </p>"+object.answer);

});
```

Comment: So when I did this ( as my string now has two pieces of data I want ), I get undefined, I can update the original post if you need to see the full output

Comment: i have updated my answer, within `$.each()` there now is object.answer instead of response[0].answer. This probably was the cause of undefined error.

Comment: Hey man! So i deleted the first comment but that's because I had entered the wrong code so duh I was getting an error, my apologies. 

I didn't seem to like the JSON.parse(data) on its own so I turned it into a String using json.stringify(data) and then parsed that data. And no matter if i stringify or not it still comes back as undefined but I'm getting an error the Dev Tools Console portion:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'answer' of null

It doesn't seem to find 'answer' in my string? Wondering if my JSON is formatted incorrectly? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Cannot read answer property of null, when you json stringify it returs a string, a string has no property because its a **STRING**. You didn't like `JSON.parse()`, I would love to know why but remember if you have lots of data in a single response, it will be tough for you to extract what you want (although not impossible). Once you get the hang of `JSON.parse()` you will always use this, because it simplifies the task for you.

Comment: Hey man! So my comment reads I didn't but it should be corrected to say "it didn't" so my apologies for the misunderstanding. Your answer helped me get going in the right direction and I have solved it. Posting an answer with the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

You need here a loop to go through your array of results and display each result

```
success: function(data) {
     var response = JSON.stringify(data);
     $('#response').delay(3600).fadeIn(600);
     $.each(response,function(index,value){//the each loop
         $('#response').append("<p>Answer: </p>"+value.answer);//get the answer using . notation 
     });
}
```